# Pygame/Python game not receiving inputs

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game on python, my problem is that I can't get the game to read inputs while running. (Not even the Escape key to exit).
I can't find the problem, I thought it was the lack of the tick method but I just added it and it still doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Here's the code:
*Edit Now just the game loop*

```
astronut=Player()
astronut.paintplayer()
while True:
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()
            if event.type == K_UP:
                astronut.acceleration +=1
                astronut.speed = astronut.speed + astronut.acceleration
                astronut.posY= astronut.posY + astronut.speed
            elif astronut.posY<(WINDOWHEIGHT-OVERTHELINE-playerHeight):
                astronut.acceleration -=1
                astronut.speed = astronut.speed + astronut.acceleration
                astronut.posY= astronut.posY + astronut.speed

    astronut.paintplayer()    
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Providing code is a great first step, but consider making an MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this will streamline our ability to help you, and you might even realize your mistake in the process of making one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check the event.key instead of event.type:

```
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            terminate()
        ...
```

Comment: Good catch. I had looked at this earlier and missed that

Comment: This is it, thank you! I knew I was overlooking something but I couldn't quite put my finger on it. I really need to sleep... Thanks.